# How to conditionally apply different webpack loaders, depending on the source entry?

Tags: express, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have a React app built with webpack, I want to ignore css module loading on some conditions.

I have 2 configurations for webpack:

1. I need to load all css modules for the **browser** build (not a problem for now)
2. I need to load css modules for the **server** only when **it's not the Server Side Rendering** (SSR) app tree

---

Here is some pseudo code for illustration (btw the app is an [OSS](https://github.com/CaliOpen/Caliopen/tree/master/src/frontend/web_application)):

```
// webpack.browser.js (standard build)
{
  entry: './client.jsx',
  module: { loaders: [ { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'] } ] },
}

// client.jsx
import App from './src/App.jsx';
// ...App includes styles

// webpack.server.js
{
  entry: './server.js',
  module: { loaders: [ 
    { 
      test: /\.scss$/, 
      loaders: [
        // may be conditionally load scss depending on which express middleware the app is builded
      ] 
     } 
  ] },
}

// server.js
// ...
import App from './src/App.jsx';
import LandingPage from './src/LandingPage.jsx';

app.use('/app', function ssrMiddleware(req, res) {
  // How to not load scss modules ?
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(App));
  res.send(html);
});

app.use('/', function websiteMiddleware(req, res) {
  // How to load scss modules ?
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(LandingPage));
  res.send(html);
});
```

---

I'm aware about [pithing loader](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html#pitching-loader), but I don't understand how it can solves my case.